# script address in master page

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, master-pages

i use this code in master page:

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#zome').cycle({
            fx: 'zoom',
            sync: false,
            delay: -2000
        });
     })
</script>
```

and i have default page and admin page: Default.aspx and Admin/Admin.aspx

javascript working in Default page but this code not working in admin page. plaes help me for path address in script.

i check this address, but is not ok!

```
/Scripts/jquery.min.js
And
~/Scripts/jquery.min.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
<script language="javascript" src='<%# ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/MyScript.js")' type="text/javascript"/>
```

Replacing the path with and file names with your own files/folder names.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ResolveUrl` in the master page as follows

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.min.js")%>'></script>

<script src='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.cycle.all.js")%>' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i use this code. and working in default.aspx but not working in admin/admin.aspx, ERROR: The Controls collection cannot be modified because the control contains code blocks (i.e. <% ... %>).

Comment: there may be some other error on the page. because the above should work.

Comment: not some other error on the page but page working without this code

Comment: ok I have changed the " into ' in the second script update it and check weather it work or not.

Comment: i use this code in admin.aspx: <%@ Register Assembly="JQControls" Namespace="JQControls" TagPrefix="jq" %>